# Using custom spring security annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3

I'm trying to make use of springs security annotations like @PreAuthorize and @Secured but Im looking to evaluate a user not on a role but whether they have permissions to a particular entity in this case a firm.  In my controller I receive a http request containing a firmId as a parameter and I want to make sure this user is permissioned to this firm.  Is this possible using the current spring security annotations?.  Im looking for an elegant solution, i've been looking at custom constraint validators as part of the jsr303 specification.  Method header below.

```
public ModelAndView getSessionsJson(HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletRequestBindingException {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like this:

```
public ModelAndView getSessionsJson(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletRequestBindingException { 
    Integer firmId = getFirmId(request);
    Firm firm = getFirmById(firmId);
    doSomeBusinessLogic(firm);
    .....
}

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#firm, 'admin')")
public void doSomeBusinessLogic(Firm firm) {
     ....
}

....
```

using [pre and post annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-pre-post-annotations) in conjuction with [ACL module](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#domain-acls). Of course before you need to set up [ACL DB schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#dbschema-acl) and prepare ACL permissions for each firm object.

Comment: I like the idea of using Access Control Lists, just curious is there any performance gains in this? because id imagine the entry table could get very big with so many users.

Comment: From the official documentation : "one of the main capabilities of the Spring Security ACL module is providing a high-performance way of retrieving ACLs". The only way to be sure that ACL is enough quick for you is fill the data and check response times.